# json file not updating properly with appendfile

Tags: node.js, json

I am posting data to the json file with the following code:

```
let productObj= {
      description: req.body.description,
      quality: req.body.quality
    };    

 fs.readFile('products.json', function (err, data) {
     let jsone= JSON.stringify(productObj);
     console.log(jsone);
      fs.appendFile("results.json", jsone, function(err){
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
      });
  });



});
```

The POST is succesful as I see in the console .However in json file the data is appended outside son object.

```
products.json:
{
"products":[

{
      "description": "Apples",
      "quality": "High",

    },
    {
      "description": "Oranges",
      "quality": "low",

    }
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appendFile` concatenates existing content with new content. Assume the following:

- Old Data: `ABC`
- New Data:    `XYZ`
- Final Data:    `ABCXYZ`

In your case, the content type is JSON which needs to be in a certain format-- `appendFile` is `contentType` agnostic which means you have to properly format/merge existing dataset with the new one and save it back to the file.

Try next code

```
 let productObj= {
   description: req.body.description,
   quality: req.body.quality
 };    

 fs.readFile('products.json', function (err, data) {
   // Convert string (old data) to JSON
   let result = JSON.parse(data);

   // Add new data to result
   result.products.push(productObj);

   // Convert JSON to string
   let jsone= JSON.stringify(result);
   console.log(jsone);
   // Replace all data in the results.json with new ones
   fs.writeFile("results.json", jsone, function(err){
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`fs.appendFile` doesn't know anything about the json structure of your file, it treats all files as text (or binary).

There are two solutions:

Every request, read the results file, parse it as json, push an element onto the end of the array, and replace the file on disk using `fs.writeFile`. This approach uses json, but isn't very reliable, as it will get slower as your file gets bigger, and it will break if multiple simultaneous requests are made.

The second option is to not use JSON. Instead, use a text based structure like below.
This allows you to freely append directly to disk as you see fit. This approach will not break if you get simultaneous requests and will stay the same speed no matter how big your results file is.

```
Apples High
Oranges Low
```