# JSON file is not updating after putting new object

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, save

I have json file which must be updated after switch button is turned off or on. However file doesn't save the new given object. Please check my code, what is wrong with it. Why the new given attribute is not updating or saving.

Here is my json file data

```
{
    "setting": [{
        "message_switch_state": "true",
        "voice_input_switch_state": "true"
    }]
}
```

and my code

```
switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {@
        Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked == true) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
                    JSONArray userArray = obj.getJSONArray("setting");
                    for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        object.remove("message_switch_state");
                        object.put("message_switch_state", "true");
                        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("states.json")) {
                            file.write(object.toString());
                            file.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String state = object.getString("message_switch_state");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                private String loadJSONFromAsset() {
                    String json = null;
                    try {
                        InputStream is = getAssets()
                            .open("states.json");
                        int size = is.available();
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                        is.read(buffer);
                        is.close();
                        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                    return json;
                }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json file not updating properly with appendfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751521/json-file-not-updating-properly-with-appendfile)

Comment: Sorry but this didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after file.flush(); you need to add file.close();

Comment: and what should have changed in the cunt, and why the code is in the loop, please tell me what the task of this program is

Comment: I have explained in the description section, please read carefully.  About the for loop, I honestly don't know my self , because this is what I've done after searching from the internet from the different resources. If you have better option I would really appreciate if you could share it with me.

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert, but it seems to be necessary to put `file.open()` before `file.flush()`